# How to get currently access class number from the beginning of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my has several div tags like following example,

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">1 - example text</div>
    <div class="content">2 - example text</div>
    <div class="content">3 - example text</div>
    <div class="content">4 - example text</div>
</div>
```

I can get the count of "content" classes using jQuery **length**

```
var numItems = $('.content').length;
```

But assume, currently I am accessing the 2nd div of the "content" class. Then how could I get, currently I am accessing the 2nd div of the **content class** from the **main class**.

Comment: use `this` context

Comment: did you mean [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `index` also.

```js
var findDiv = $('.main').find("div");
alert($(findDiv[1]).html());
console.log(findDiv[1])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">1 - example text</div>
    <div class="content">2 - example text</div>
    <div class="content">3 - example text</div>
    <div class="content">4 - example text</div>
</div>
```